# IE issue:addEventListener

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Jquery.min.js file contains addEventListener text within.on browsing my website in IE the console displays error at addEventListener. Due to this error no other files like css,js that are dependent on jQuery was able to load.Finally the page displays very crumbled due to css and js files unloaded.

I have added below code in   and that helped to resolve the problem:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
```

If anyone has other solution please suggest.

The above code solves compatibility problems with IE versions.

Comment: Could you tell us the IE version and the jQuery version too? That would help recreating your problem.

Comment: `addEventListener` was only added in Internet Explorer 9. jQuery 2.x versions support IE 9 and up, while jQuery 1.x versions contain `attachEvent` logic and support IE 8 and below.